# glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred - How to solve

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I keep getting this message

glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

How do i go about this? I also get only 1 or 0 when I try the ctree package.

I dont know how to resolve it, the result for the logistic regression output are here[image: Logistic Regression result]

Comment: it's called separation, see https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/

Comment: you can consider the solutions raised in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression